# Getting google spreadsheets to send me an email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet on Google spreadsheets that has "D2" through all of "D" (because it will expand as used and when I add more) with a drop down box for priority status. The drop down has "Low, Medium, High". I want to get a script to send me an email when that priority gets edited to "High"

This is the script I did last night at 2AM half asleep.

`````
{
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("TC52 Bugs or Issues and Improvements.");

var valueToCheck = sheet.getRange(D).getValue();

var rangeEdit = e.range.getA1Notation();

if(rangeEdit == "D")

{
if(valueToCheck > High) 
        {
        MailApp.sendEmail("austin.hendrix@decathlon.com", "High Priority please check now.", "Check spreadsheet" + valueToCheck+ ".");
        }
}
}````
`````

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails) article has a tutorial.

On that note, something along the lines of (Heavily edited by **MetaMan**)

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(1,4,sh.getLastRow()) or getRange('D1:D'+sh.getLastRow()));
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = "youremail@email.com"; // First column
    var message = "High priority set with data in A column "+sheet.getRange(("A"+i+1)).getValues()[0]; // Second column
    var subject = 'High priority set in D'+i;
    if(row[0]=="High"){
       MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: @MetaMan I've edited it as such, I had to write this up in a hurry

Comment: @MetaMan Edited the +1 to `A` column, ya spend too long working with 0start arrays and it starts to affect you yaknow? :P

In regards to var, I am keeping as it is stated to be good practice as per https://spreadsheet.dev/loops-apps-script

Comment: @MetaMan bless you man/woman . 
Have edited my answer and given due credit

Answer (score 0):

The function will send you an email when column D is edited to "High".

You will need to fill in 'Your Spreadsheet name' the recipient email address and what ever subject you wish.  Also you can edit the body as well. The current body just tells you which row issue the email.  Alternately, if you wish to provide more information I'll do it for you.

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == 'Your Sheet Name' && e.range.columnStart == 4 && e.range.rowStart >1 && e.value == 'High') {
    GmailApp.sendEmail('recipient','subject',`row ${e.range.rowStart} has been set to high`)
  }
}
```

> Since sending an email requires permission you will have to create an installable trigger for this function.

You can do it manually or use a function like the one below which will prevent you from creating more that one trigger.

```
function createTrigger() {
  const ts = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().map(t=>t.getHandlerFunction());
  if(!~ts.indexOf('onMyEdit')) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('onMyEdit').forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId()).onEdit().create();
  }
}
```

[ScriptApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app)

> Please Note: that you cannot run onEdit triggered functions from the Script Editor or even from a menu.  They require the onEdit trigger which populates the single parameter e with the event object.  You can run them from another function as long as it provides the event object.

Comment: Will this trigger even if someone else makes that edit? The top one I mean.

Comment: If you are sharing with them then they will be required to install the trigger also and authorize the script.